# How do I send attachments with Zend_Mail?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, attachment

```
<?php

$message=$_POST['feedback'];
$attachments=$_POST['file'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$tosend=$_POST['to'];
$tocc=$_POST['cc'];

$mail = new Zend_Mail();

$mail->setFrom('user@example.com','Admin');
$mail->addTo($tosend, 'Some Recipient');
$mail->addCc($tocc);

$mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBodyHtml($message);

$attachments = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($attachments));

$attachments->type = '.txt';        
$attachments->filename = "";

$mail->send($transport);
?>
```

With this code i'm not able to open files, its taking just the file name not the entire path to open attachments, When i click to open the attachment its giving error as failed to open stream.

And this code is working fine with other features like cc Bcc and all

Answer (score 3):

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyHtml("description");
$mail->setFrom('id', 'name');
$mail->addTo(email, name);
$mail->setSubject(subject);

$content = file_get_contents("path to pdf file"); // e.g. ("attachment/abc.pdf")
$attachment = new Zend_Mime_Part($content);
$attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
$attachment->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
$attachment->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$attachment->filename = 'filename.pdf'; // name of file

$mail->addAttachment($attachment);                  

$mail->send();
```

Comment: this is for type pdf , you can change that as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the `$_FILES` array to open the file, not `$_POST`. `$_POST` only contains the filename, `$_FILES` contains the actual file.

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

---

Additionally, `Zend_Mime_Part::type` expects an MIME type, i.e. `$attachments->type` needs to be an MIME type. For text files this is `text/plain`. I also don't think you can set an empty filename.

Comment: I have followed your answer, still I'm not able to find out.  $message=$_POST['feedback'];
$attachments=$_FILES['file'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$tosend=$_POST['to'];
$tocc=$_POST['cc'];

Answer (score 0):

please try this, it will work.

```
 $file = "path of file";

 $mail = new Zend_Mail();
 $mail->setFrom("test@test.com", "test");
 $mail->addTo("test1@test.com", "test user");
 $mail->setSubject("file mail");
 $mail->setBodyHtml("html");   
 $at = new Zend_Mime_Part(file_get_contents($file));
 $at->type        = mime_content_type($file);
 $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
 $at->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
 $at->filename    = basename($file);

 $mail->addAttachment($at); 

 if($mail->send())
 {
          echo " sent";
 }
 else
 {
      echo "not sent";
 }

 ?>
```